# How to only update formulas which resulted in error values?

Tags: excel

I have a large workbook and it takes me a long time to update even a single worksheet.

Is there any command to tell excel to only evaluate cells with formulas that resulted in error?

Comment: evaluate and update meaning what? recalculation? Looking for errors?

Comment: Evaluate the formulae

Comment: meaning look for formulas that result in errors, or formulas that are wrong?

Comment: I am looking for a command to update Formulas that evaluated in errors. e.g. #VALUE or #REF

Comment: update with what? If they are errors you must resolve the reasons. If you want to find all errors on a sheet  that is a different task. You can use formula auditing tool bar or adjust the formula to never return errors with functions for that purpose, or edit>goto>special>formulas>errors. Which do you need?

Comment: Exactly, I solved the reasons. Now I need to update the cells...

Comment: if the reasons are solved then re-calculating the worksheet will fix that. F9 or Shift+F9

Comment: My point is that my worksheet is too large, so I would like to only update the formulae with errors

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to partially calculate a sheet, if that is what you mean. If you actually fixed errors they will disappear in a recalculation

Answer (score 0):

No.

Active Worksheet Calculation (keystroke: SHIFT+F9 rather than keystroke: F9 or keystroke: CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F9 (introduced in Excel 2002)) already only recalculates the cells marked for calculation (in the active worksheet only).

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891%28v=office.15%29.aspx)